# Could not install package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 2.0.1'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget-package

Background: I had Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 2.0.1' and tried to upgrade to the the newest version 3.6.0 in Visual Studio 2017 in my web project using the Nuget package manager and get the error:

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 3.6.0'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with 
that framework.
```

I tried to go back to the version 2.0.1 and it won't install that now either, even though that was the version that was installed before I tried to upgrade. I can uninstall all of it, but then I 'think' I am not using the Roselyn compiler (do I need to?).
Any help would be appreicated either to get the newest version installed, get 2.01 installed, or a clear answer that I don't need the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't the error message clarify the issue?

Comment: Not for me.  How would your proceed from that message?

Comment: The package you are trying to install does not match the target framework (4.0) of you project. Unless you have a compelling reason not to, I would update the target framework of the project.

Comment: It all worked fine at 4.0 before with version 2.0.1.  The target IIS server only goes to 4.0 framework, so going to 4.5 is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite late for the answer, still if someone stumbles upon this even now they might give a try to this solution.
You can not install any Package that does not support the Underlying framework.
'*Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform version 3.6.0*' is meant for the higher version of .net framework that is 4.5 or greater.

So below steps can be followed for moving back to compatible version.

1. Try Running the `Uninstall-package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform version 3.6.0`.
2. Delete the packages folder and bin folder.
3. Run the command `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform version` again without mentioning the version information. It will try to get the relevant package automatically.